# What kind of links does Bing API's Deeplink contains?

Tags: bing-api, deep-linking

I am writing code that uses Bing Search API and bumped in Deeplink which is a class that contains links of a each webpage that was found according to the user's query.

What kind of links does DeepLink contains? is it an array of Primary links? Internal web links? or else; **every** link that appear in the web page code is located in the array?

Thanks